# cakephp211 saving data erros (associated tables)

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I have two associated tables (customers hasmany commands) and this is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Customer');?>
echo $this->Form->input('Client.name', array('disabled' => true,'value' =>  'francis')); 
echo $this->Form->input('Command.0.the_date');
echo $this->Form->end(__('save'));?>
```

and this is my function:

```
public function add() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        unset($this->Customer->Command->validate['customers_id']);
        $this->Customer->saveAssociated($this->request->data);    
    }
}
```

But when i process to save data, nothing happens! 
Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what $this->request->data looks like in the controller after the POST ?

Comment: thanks men! i found! the input must be actived:  'disabled' => false

Answer (score 0):

Please use this line on your controller

```
var $uses = array('Customer','Command');

public function add() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        unset($this->Customer->Command->validate['customers_id']);
        $this->Customer->saveall($this->request->data);    
    }
}
```